# How to get the position of element from matplotlib pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a plot and I am using `matplotlib` to plot x vs y. Both x and y are an array of 500 elements. I am interested in getting the position of the element in the list of the array from the plot. If I can get the actual element, I can find the position of the element. Can you please help me regarding the same? Either finding the element position or element itself?

Comment: The question is very confusing. Maybe [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is helpful?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Do you want to find the x and y values of a particular marker in the plot?

Comment: Sorry for that @SinanKurmus. Yes either the x and y values of the particular marker or the corresponding position of the x and y values in the array. For eg., if x = [1 2 3 4 5] and y = [6 7 8 9 10] and I plot them and afterwards I click on 3rd point, I want to either get the value of x and y i.e. (3,8)  or preferred would be the index or the position of x and y in the array corresponding to the marker i.e. (3,3)

Answer (score 0):

You need an interactive plot. As [@JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12046409/johanc) suggested [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) would be an option if you want to stick with matplotlib. [Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/) would definitely do what you need. [Bokeh](https://bokeh.org/) too probably.